# Too many loop devices on system monitor

Tags: partitioning, system-monitor, loop-device

I too have the same issue in Ubuntu 19.04 (had it back in 16.04, but removed the entire snap).

I can't remove bunch of snap images since I am not sure whether I need them (e.g. Yaru theme, etc...)

Any ideas to hide them from the System Monitor?

[image: System Monitor Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known *feature* of the system monitor application: since 18.04 (I guess) the system monitor is no longer installed as a regular package but as a snap instead. And that snap version displays all the other loop devices needed for the other snaps. I consider this a bug. I'm not interested in dozens of technical filesystems that are deliberately 100 % in use and just distract me from the important ones.

Get rid of the snap version and install the classic package instead:

```
snap remove gnome-system-monitor        # no sudo required
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```